# How to get access to my own post?

Tags: support

I posted a question about Ramsey Optimal Taxation a day ago. Since I didn't have an account back then, I have lost access to the question. Here's the link to the question: [Ramsey Optimal Tax](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/53105/ramsey-optimal-tax).

@Mods: Is there a way you can give me access to the question? I was planning to set a bounty as it has not attracted a comment or an answer since I posted it.